# Ubunbtu 12.10 and Acer Aspire 5315 overheat/fan problem

Tags: 12.10, acer, aspire

I know this question has been asked and answered before, but the solutions do not seem to be relevant for 12.10.  The acer_fancontrol script is out of date, directories are not the same anymore and acer aspires are coming out with more RAM than 512MB.

What is the fix in 12.10?

Answer (score 1):

you should consider installing jupiter

you can select power modes with it, its very easy to control, and I just set it to power on command, you won't notice that your laptop is on, until you start using heavy apps

open terminal and do this.

add the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
```

update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

install jupiter

```
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

and to other people reading this and are using an Asus EEPC netbook, install this asswell

```
sudo apt-get install jupiter-support-eee
```

Have a nice day :)